# python Elasticsearch memory issue

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, memory-leaks

We are using python2.7, with elasticsearch==5.0.1 client.
When running our application, we noticed that the memory increases, and after a while we reach OOM.

I used memory_profiler to investigate, and noticed that when we are trying to use the bulk function from elasticsearch helpers, the memory increases and does not being released.

We tried forcing GC to collect unused data, I added time.sleep (my first thought was that elasticsearch still streaming the data).

Does anyone else had an issue with elasticsearch bulk and have a solution?

Here is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, serializer, compat, exceptions, RequestsHttpConnection
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, MultiSearch

class JSONSerializerPython2(serializer.JSONSerializer):
  def dumps(self, data):
    import json
    # don't serialize strings
    if isinstance(data, compat.string_types):
        return data
    try:
        return json.dumps(data, default=self.default, ensure_ascii=True)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        logger.error(e)
        raise exceptions.SerializationError(data, e)

class ElasticSearchDriver(object):
  def __init__(self, index_name, host, doc_type=None, max_size_connections=100):
    """
    :param index_name: (String)
    :param host: (String)
    :param doc_type: (String)
    :param max_size_connections: (Int)
    """
    self.es = None
    self.index_name = index_name
    self.es_search = None
    self.doc_type = doc_type

    es_connection_dict = {"hosts": host, "serializer": JSONSerializerPython2(), "maxsize": max_size_connections,}

    try:
        # create the connection object
        self.es = Elasticsearch(**es_connection_dict)
    except Exception as msg:
        logger.error(msg)
        raise ValueError("Error: ElasticSearchDriver.__init__-{0}".format(msg))

  @retry(stop_max_attempt_number=STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER, wait_exponential_multiplier=WAIT_EXPONENTIAL_MULTIPLIER,
   wait_exponential_max=WAIT_EXPONENTIAL_MAX, retry_on_exception=exception_elasticsearch)
  @profile
  def upsert_data_bulk(self, key, data_json_list, inline_script, retry_on_conflict=5):
    """
    :param key: (String)
    :param data_json_list: (Dict)
    :param inline_script: (String)
    :param retry_on_conflict: (Boolean)
    :return: answer (String/Dict)
    """
    from datetime import datetime

    actions = list()
    for data_json in data_json_list:
        data_dict = {
            "_op_type": "update",
            "_index": self.index_name,
            "_type": key,
            "retry_on_conflict": retry_on_conflict,
            "_source": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "inline": inline_script,
                    "params": data_json
                },
                "upsert": data_json
            }
        }

        if "system_write_at" not in data_json:
           system_write_at = datetime.utcnow()
           data_dict["_source"]["script"]["params"]["system_write_at"] = system_write_at
           data_dict["_source"]["upsert"]["system_write_at"] = system_write_at

        if "es_id" in data_json:
            data_dict["_id"] = data_json["es_id"]

        actions.append(data_dict)

    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print "------------"
    print process.memory_info()[0]

    x = bulk(self.es, actions, request_timeout=120)
    print process.memory_info()[0]
    # time.sleep(120)
    print process.memory_info()[0]

    actions = None
    x = None
    gc.collect()
    print process.memory_info()[0]
    print "------------"

    return x
```

the memory_info that were printed:

```
------------
122753024 .  # before bulk
192577536 .  # after bulk
192577536
192577536
------------
```

The output of memory_profile:
[image]

at line 279, we can see the bulk adds 67M to the memory.
Are we using it right?
We're really stuck over here

Comment: try to not create a list - actions - with all the operation in RAM, but to manage them with a function generator, the yield statement. You could also try parallel_bulk, that is a generator, instead bulk

Comment: you could also increase ram dedicated to elasticsearch in java virtual machine, editing jvm.options

Comment: we having the same issue when query the elastic search memory increases upto 100MB, any luck you got any solution you found